# Will playstore reject apps with armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 but no x86-64 support?

Tags: android, arm, x86-64, arm64, armv7

From android developer website, https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit it is clear that starting August 1, 2019, apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures.

Our current app has native libraries for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 ABIs but no x86-64. This is because one of the cordova plugins we are using doesn't provide X86-64 support.

Will playstore reject the app update or pass it considering there is arm64-v8a support or we will have to drop support for x86 to stay compliant?

Comment: By 64-bit they mostly mean arm64. I'm not sure about x86-64, but alot of apps already don't even include x86, and you still see them on play store (examples are Facebook and Tinder)

Comment: [How to make APK compliant with Google Play 64-bit Requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710677) says you need to support the *corresponding* 64-bit architecture for any 32-bit version you ship. So x86-64 if there's an x86 version, and ARM64 if there's an ARM version.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**

Unity Technologies' User *ScottF* (1) confirmed with Google representatives:

> "...you would indeed need to drop x86 in order to be compliant with
>   their 64bit requirement."

I've personally dropped the support today for x86 in Google Play Store for an Android App built with Unity.
I've just got a warning that I will lose support from **2 devices from a total a 10867 previously supported**.

[image: Dropping support on x86 in Google Play]

**Some extra info:**

- Unity is dropping support on Android x86 and x86_64 (1)
- According to some sources from Unity, Intel processor on Android is virtually dead. (2) (3)

[image]

**Source:**

1 - https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/

2 - https://forum.unity.com/threads/wheres-the-unity-stats-page-gone.514106/

3 - https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-x86_64-support.711869/

Comment: x86_64 powers most of the Chromebooks, which run Android apps naturally. True, this may not be very important for Unity games.