# Is an x86_64 version sufficient to distribute an arm32 version in Google Play instead of an arm64 version?

Tags: android, arm, google-play, x86-64, google-play-console

Google Play requires to support 64-bit version of an app from Aug. 2019.

Therefore, I cannot update my app since then.
This is because it is difficult for me to build an arm64 version of my app, which is based on an open source project called mozc.

However, I may be able to create an x86_64 version of my app.

Is an x86_64 version sufficient to distribute an arm32 version in Google Play even if I do not create an arm64 version?

Comment: [How to make APK compliant with Google Play 64-bit Requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710677) says you need to support the *corresponding* 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Also, this ruling is because the latest Arm CPU designs and devices based on them are moving to 64-bit only. Any 32-bit-only apps will increasingly be unable to run.