# Android Studio - Can I exclude x86 and x64 so file?

Tags: android

I had an app that uses a third party library, this library only provide armv7 and x86 .so file, and when i try to upload to play console, google gave me an error "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.".

On this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709272/how-to-make-apk-compliant-with-google-play-64-bit-requirement), i learn that I can exclude x86 to mute this error.

My question is, by excluding x86 .so file, will my app have problem on some android devices? crash etc..

Comment: Which library is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put armv7 and x86 .so library into relevant x64 version direction

Such as:
put armv7-a.so into arm and arm64 library direction;

put x86.so into x86 and x64 library direction;

Create relevant direction just like ["this answer you post"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709272/how-to-make-apk-compliant-with-google-play-64-bit-requirement) did

create a x64 direction and put x86.so into it

PS:The best way is that compile third party source code until all cpus type are supported

Comment: Not "until" ;It is  "make sure"

Comment: Just to make sure, by "You can put armv7 and x86 .so library into relevant x64 version direction", you mean create a "arm64" folder, can copy paste armv7 and x86 .so file into the folder, right?

Comment: put arm .so lib into arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a folder

Comment: and put x86 version .so lib file into x86. and x86_64 folder

Comment: Which means you have to create 4 folders for your project